# How to generate the ActionScript 3 source code of an OpenLaszlo LZX SWF runtime app

Tags: actionscript, openlaszlo, lzx

When developing OpenLaszlo applications, it's sometimes useful to generate the ActionScript 3 source code of an application written in [lzx](/questions/tagged/lzx), e.g. when you want to compile OpenLaszlo into an Adobe AIR application.

What is the simplest way to generate the ActionScript 3 source code into a predefined folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lzc` command line tool which can be found in the `$LPS_HOME/WEB-INF/lps/server/bin/` has on option for that:

```
--lzxonly
  for as3 runtime, emit intermediate as files, 
  but don't call backend as3 compiler
```

By default the OpenLaszlo compiler will generate the ActionScript 3 code into the system specific Java temp folder, but the `$JAVA_OPTS` environment variable can be used to change that folder.

Here's an example of how the command can be used in combination with `$JAVA_OPTS` on Linux:

**a)  Create a simple LZX file, e.g.**

```
<canvas>  
  <button text="Hello world" />  
</canvas>
```

and save it as `test.lzx`.

**b) Set the `$JAVA_OPTS` variable**
The following syntax is for Linux or OS X:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=./tmp -DXmx1024M"
```

**c) Compile the LZX into ActionScript 3**

```
> lzc --lzxonly test.lzx --runtime=swf10
Compiling: test.lzx to test.swf10.swf
```

The `tmp` folder will contain the generated ActionScript 3 files

```
tmp
├── lzccache
└── lzswf9
    └── build
        └── test
            ├── app.swf
            ├── build.sh
            ├── LzApplication.as
            ├── $lzc$class_basebutton.as
            ├── $lzc$class_basecomponent.as
            ├── $lzc$class_basefocusview.as
            ├── $lzc$class_button.as
            ├── $lzc$class__componentmanager.as
            ├── $lzc$class_focusoverlay.as
            ├── $lzc$class__m2u.as
            ├── $lzc$class__m2v.as
            ├── $lzc$class__m2w.as
            ├── $lzc$class__m2x.as
            ├── $lzc$class__m2y.as
            ├── $lzc$class__m2z.as
            ├── $lzc$class__m30.as
            ├── $lzc$class__m31.as
            ├── $lzc$class__mm.as
            ├── $lzc$class__mn.as
            ├── $lzc$class__mo.as
            ├── $lzc$class__mp.as
            ├── $lzc$class_statictext.as
            ├── $lzc$class_style.as
            ├── $lzc$class_swatchview.as
            ├── LZC_COMPILER_OPTIONS
            ├── LzPreloader.as
            └── LzSpriteApplication.as
```

The folder structure follows the following scheme:

`{JAVA_TEMP_FOLDER}/lzswf9/build/{LZX_FILENAME_WITHOUT_ENDING}`, therefore in our case

```
tmp/lzswf9/build/test/
```

The main applicaton file is `LzSpriteApplication.as`, and you can look into the build.sh file to get an idea how the Flex SDK's `mxmlc` command is used to compile the generated source code.